# Building workspace creating a prob in eclipse for android app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-luna

I have installed **android sdk** from **google website** and and **android plugin** from **eclipse (add new software)**.
 All my sdk and avd are working fine, but I was creating a new project, it shows me this message.
**I am using mac, my java version is 1.7**
I already tried all the solutions from stackoverflow and other websites mentioned related to this question.
I try to restart my eclipse several times and try to update sdk, but it doesn't help me in any way.

[image: Snapshot of message]

Comment: Try to reinstall eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If you used Netbeans thancheck workspace of it if both eclips and Netbeans work space same than this problem is occures. please either remove Netbeans or change workspace of Eclips.

Comment: I am not using netbeans. Please suggest me some other solution.

Comment: I have  updated jdk and jre, but still i'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps
1. Close Eclipse, and go to the error occurring workspace folder delete the .metaData folder again open the eclipse with the same workspace
2. or create new workspace and import all the project to the new workspace.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is not solving my problem. Please suggest some other solution.